# Is there a way to check if an element has a class in cypress.io?

Tags: cypress

I don't want to test that it has the class like `...should('have.class', "some-class")` I just want know if it does, and if doesn't then perform some action that gives it that class.

Basically, I want to see if the element has `Mui-checked` and if it doesn't them programmatically check it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [hasClass()](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) jquery method for this:

```js
cy.get('selector').then(($ele) => {
  if ($ele.hasClass('foo')) {
    //Do something when you have the class
  } else {
    //Do something when you don't have the class
  }
})
```

Answer (score 16):

Generally it's bad practice to do `if() else()` in a test.

You would want to make the test as ***deterministic*** as possible to avoid flaky tests.

In your example, if the class is added asynchronously the `if()` check may be executed too soon.

Instead, add the class directly. You don't need to check the condition since `$el.addClass()` does not fail even if the element already has the class.

```js
cy.get('selector').then($el => $el.addClass("blue"))
```

Comment: The asker seems to want to use the UI to make the change rather than just forcing the class.

Comment: Well, he does say ***programmatically*** but semantics aside, the idea is to avoid conditional code in the test to avoid flaky tests. Generally it's bad practice to do `if() else()` if the class is added asynchronously, since the `if()` may be executed too soon.

Answer (score 6):

Colin's idea is on the right track, but `.and('contain', 'some-class')` still causes the test to fail (it's just a synonym for `should`).

Change it to `.then()` to check the classList:

```js
cy.get('div')
  .should('have.attr', 'class')
  .then(classList => {
    const classes = classList.split(' ')
    if (classes.includes('some-class')) {
      // ... action when class is found
    }
  })
```

**Note**

Perform the conditional check as late as possible, in this case after `.should('have.attr', 'class')` which **retries** until the classlist is attached.

If you follow the accepted answer, you have chance of a **flaky test**.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the `class` attribute with `should()` and check that it contains your class, something like:

```
cy.get('.selector')
  .should('have.attr', 'class')
  .and('contain', 'some-class');
```

Comment: The question is about how to identify the presence of a class without the test failing.
But FYI, if you do want the test to fail you can use .should('have.class', 'some-class'), which should produce fewer false positives than the code you posted.

Comment: @Jacob - I agree. I didn't realise `have.class` would validate a single class amongst many.  Good to know, thanks.